# SQLite with WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider Long to Int Cast Error

Tags: asp.net-membership, membership-provider, webmatrix, simplemembership, webmatrix-2

I'm trying to use the `SimpleMembershipProvider` with SQLite to enable authentication on my site. I have it initialized in my `Global.aspx` and can create users, however I can't log users in. I get the following error when I try to call `WebSecurity.Login([UserName], [Password])`:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The stack trace is as follows (after I make the call to the `Login` function:

```
CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object ) +146
System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1(CallSite site, T0 arg0) +661
WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.VerifyUserNameHasConfirmedAccount(IDatabase db, String username, Boolean throwException) +315
WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +162
WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login(String userName, String password, Boolean persistCookie) +32
```

I know that SQLite only allows `Int64` values in numeric columns (that aren't `float`). The question is: how do I get the `SimpleMembershipProvider` to work with `Int64` values? I had a look at the source code for the offending routines listed in the stack trace and it seems that all numbers are being explicitly cast before being returned from their `Int32` functions. However, I don't have the source to `System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1` or `CallSite.Target`, so I can't see what is going on there. What is more, those are probably pre-compiled. So, the question remains, how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SimpleMembership Provider only supports SQL Server and SQL Compact 4.0. SQLite is not supported. If you want to use SQLite, you will have to create your own implementation of ExtendedMembershipProvider. You can more or less copy [SimpleMembershipProvider.cs](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/5cb74eb3b2f3#src/WebMatrix.WebData/SimpleMembershipProvider.cs), and just modify the bits where the data type conflict arises.

Comment: that is what I suspected. I was hoping there was another way. I ended up writing my own custom provider (which, with EF, was surprisingly easy). There were just too many problems copying `SimpleMembershipProvider.cs`. Thanks for your help though. Hopefully they will eventually support SQLite, especially since it is opensource now.

Comment: I doubt "they" (Microsoft) will ever produce a SQLite membership provider since it's so easy for you to create your own. That's the whole point of the provider model - so that they don't have to write the code for every conceivable data source.